# Php curl output blank in my case

Tags: php, curl

```
<?php


// 1. initialize
$ch = curl_init();

// 2. set the options, including the url
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://somesite.edu");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

// 3. execute and fetch the resulting HTML output
$output = curl_exec($ch);

echo $output;

// 4. free up the curl handle
curl_close($ch);

?>
```

I use npm curl and it did retrieved something but when I try in php it return blank. What's my problem? I already said CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER to true.

Comment: I tested your script and it returns content for me. Also SSL verification does not seem to be the problem. Perhaps you are banned or the servers expects some more headers (e.g. accept, useragent)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add another option on your curl:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
```

Comment: is this for curling https ?